# Syntax error only on internet Explorer on a typscript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, syntax-error

On a project, I use a typescript file :

```
export const isMobile = (): boolean => {

      let check = false;
      (function (a) { if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).[...]mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|.vendor);
      return check;
    }

    export const isTablet = (): boolean => {
      let check = false;
      (function (a) { if (/(android|iPad)|/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor);
      return check;
    }

    export const breakpointSizes = {
      t: 768,
      m: 1000,
      ml: 1280,
      l: 1600,
      xl: 1920,
    }

    export const resetActiveState = (className: string) => {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll(`.${className}`),
        (card: HTMLElement) => {
          card.classList.remove('is-active')
        },
      )
    }
```

Everything is fine on Firefox, google chrome, Edge and Safari. 
But on Internet explorer I have the error : syntax error. 
I also use gulp for my ts file to render the code readable but here I don't get where the syntax error is, could anyone help on this ? 
Here is the compilated code :

```
exports.isMobile = function () {
  var check = false; 
  (function (a) {
    if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true;
  })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor);  
  return check;
};

exports.isTablet = function () {
  var check = false; 

  (function (a) {
    if (/(android|iPad)|/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true;
  })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor);

  return check;
};

exports.breakpointSizes = {
  t: 768,
  m: 1000,
  ml: 1280,
  l: 1600,
  xl: 1920
};

exports.resetActiveState = function (className) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".".concat(className)), function (card) {
    card.classList.remove('is-active');
  });
};
```

Comment: The browser will not see the TypeScript code at all. It will only see the compiled JavaScript call, so show us that. Also, show us your compiler options - you're most likely not compiling to ES5.

Comment: @VLAZ I edited my post :)

Comment: `if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+[...]amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu))` - this is not syntactically correct. It has a starting `/` but no finishing one, so it cannot be parsed as a regex literal. However, you should be getting the same problem in all browsers - it's equally invalid everywhere.

Comment: @VLAZ I cut my code because it was too long and I thought that it won't pass, I edited my post with the complete regex

Comment: Same problem, now you have a missing ending `/` in the second regex in the same `if`

Comment: I don't see it, could you point the part code please ?

Comment: Fourth line, it's the `if` statement. The second part of it after the `||` starts with `/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu` but the regex is never closed.

Comment: @VLAZ Well I'm sorry, I think my code wasn't paste well, I edited my post with the all regex

Comment: I don't get a syntax error any more. This works. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: @VLAZ I think the error is on the line `exports.isMobile = function () ` I have a mark here on my browser ( if to be honest I never use IE so i'm not sure about it)